# Retrieving all Cookies in JMeter and to pass in subsequent requests

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

While recording I can see the all cookies are stored in the request headers as
JSESSIONID=71fc7095-b591-4106-b904-9f5XXXXX58c3; _uid=user-5664708212484720511; oxy_lang=en_US; test-cookie=test; rsession-key=dvQ2PWXXXXXXXXXXm52E3; ALFRESCO_REMEMBER_ME=1

But when I am replying the script, it is not pulling all the cookies to the request. I am getting only few cookies as below.

Cookie Data:
JSESSIONID=dd043e4f-e740-4677-a578-65XXXXXcd029; _uid=user511841202XXXXX5292

How can I retrieve all cookies ?

Note: I added HTTP Cookie Manager to the test plan and changed the configuration in JMeter properties file as CookieManager.save.cookies=true

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Cookie Manager should automatically add the cookies in case if they're **valid**, to wit:

- domain and path of the next request match the ones in the cookie
- cookie is not expired
- protocol matches cookie's `secure` attribute

So if JMeter doesn't send all the cookies most probably the system under test is not properly configured.

If you're absolutely sure that your system under test is okay you can do the following:

- Choose less restrictive implementation in the HTTP Cookie Manager, i.e. `netscape`

  [image]
- add the next line to *user.properties* file:

  ```
  CookieManager.check.cookies=false
  ```

More information:

- [HTTP State Management Mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)
- [JMeter Properties Reference - Miscellaneous configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager)

Comment: My I know what is meant by " the system under test is not properly configured."

Comment: Please suggest what corrections I need to make ?

Comment: Excellent answer.